How to read and grep a message echoed to standard output in bash?
I have a bash script that downloads information from a sever using rsync.  This script runs on remote client machines.  Occasionally, I will get error messages because the server IP may have changed or we have a new server.  So for example, I will get a message like this:
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'example.com' differs from the key for the IP address 'x.x.x.x.'
Offending key for IP in /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:5
Matching host key in /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:6

And also messages like:
WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!

with of course a whole bunch of messages.  I want to delete the key using ssh-keygen etc.  This happened recently because we moved our server. I don't want to delete the key if it has happened already and I don't want to do all this manually to 30 machines.  So how do I catch those strings shown above and if they exist, run the ssh-keygen command.  Something like this for the first case (to remove the cached key):
if grep -<options> "Warning: the ECDSA host key for" <output>
then
    ssh-keygen -R x.x.x.x
else
   echo "You are all set!"
fi

Note:  This is fairly secure because the script is downloaded dynamically and deletes itself once it runs.

Can't you just pipe rsync into grep?

@Verpous How?  I am an amateur at bash.

Piping connects the stdout of one command to the stdin of the next. You pipe commands with the | operator, it will look something like: rsync <args> | grep <args>. This is a shell scripting 101, I suggest finding a bash tutorial and learning the basics, any tutorial you find will teach this.

@Chiwda: Would it be easier to make rsync ignore host identification ? in ssh, I use the options -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new for that. Note that removing host identification should only be done in environment you control (but I assume this is ok in your case as it is no less secure than accepting the new host without checks)

@Verpous Error messages go to stderr, so you need 2>&1 | grep ...

This worked!
if (rsync -ratlzvP --rsh="sshpass -p xxxxxx ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l XXXXXX" XXXXXX@example.com:/var/www/example.com/XXXXXX/Stretch/xxxx.sh ./  2>&1 | grep  'receiving incremental file list')
then
echo "Good!"
else
echo "Error condition"
fi

Thanx to @Barmar and @Verpous for incremental clues.  I am posting the above in case it helps someone else. Suggestions to improve the answer are welcome.

There's no reason to spawn a subshell to run the command, as wrapping it in (...) does, just do if rsync ... | grep ...; then instead of if (rsync ... | grep ...); then to run it in the current shell. You might also want to add the -q argument to grep if you just want to test its exit status and don't need to see its output.
